Can I modify VSCode syntax highlighting so that a python parameter variable's color is different from function call keyword parameter names?
I was able to modify both the color of parameter variables and function call keyword parameter names at the same time, but I cannot seem to modify them separately.
For example the following:
{
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "variable.parameter",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ec9"
                }
            }
        ],
    }
}

results in:

But what I want is to have the a in a= to remain the original colour (gray in my case).
Is it possible to change the color of parameter variables and function call keyword parameters separately?

VS Code uses TextMate grammars for syntax highlighting,
and the granularity of the highlighting depends on the specific grammar being used. You could consider opening a feature request on the VS Code GitHub repository or the repository for the Python extension.
